# UIButton Difficult to Press Near iPhone Edges

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7

I'm having a problem with UIButtons responding to a tap near the edge of an iPhone. After creating a new XCode project, dragging a button to my viewcontroller in storyboard near the left-lower corner, and running the simulator, the button appears to respond nicely to any tap over the entire surface area of the button.

*However*, if I run the program on an iPhone, the UIButton takes about 1 second to register with the lower-half of the button but will register immediately for the upper half of the button. Why is this? Then, when I drag the button towards the center of the iPhone screen, it registers a tap at any point across the button surface area immediately.

Try running an app with a button near the edge for yourself - do you get the same result?

[image]

Here is a screen shot of the lower-left corner of my viewcontroller - nothing special at all. I simply have a viewcontroller with buttons added along the bottom edge of the iPhone.

---

**EDIT**

Although I have not yet resolved this issue, I have discovered that the Control Center and Notification center features of the iPhone are interfering with my buttons. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller??

Comment: No, just a viewcontroller with buttons in storyboard.

Comment: if just in the lower-left corner or all over the bottom??

Comment: I have buttons all over the bottom - but they all react to the same issue. I tried moving buttons to the left/right edges of the iPhone and the buttons work perfectly (I can tap anywhere on them and they respond immediately). So something is wrong with the top/bottom edges.

Comment: ooohh I see... it must be for the Control center and the notification center. Disable them, and verify again.

Comment: How do I disable them?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well... the problem that you have is because, when you tap on the bottom or on the top of the app, there is a gesture that verify if you swipe up or down. If you do, it will show you the Notification Center or Control Center. If you don't swipe and you hold the tap, first verify if it is a swipe and then recognize your tap. Thats's the reason of the delay. These gestures can't be disabled via code.

Comment: The Facebook or Pinterest apps, etc. do not have a delay and their buttons are directly on the bottom. From what I recall you can still use the notification/control center feature in those apps without delay?

Comment: Oh, so Facebook and Pinterest added additional code to detect whether the gesture was a swipe or tap - correct? I will have to condition this via obj-c.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46888/discussion-between-soto-ighost-and-biff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to my ViewController.m resolved the issue:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```